# Excel crashes when install an addin

Tags: excel, installation, add-in

Excel AddIn, .NET 4.0, NetOffice 1.5.1.2,  ExcelDNA 1.29, C#
installers calls a xls (install.xls) with VBA as follow 
At the end of install.xls, Excel will close. 
However, after Excel closes,  Excel crashes saying "Excel stops working... please send report to Microsoft" with two buttons, one is "Don't Send", the other is send

This ONLY happens on Windows XP + Excel 2007 or WinXP + Excel 2010. 
Also during debug I notice if I replace Application.Wait  with MsgBox, then there is no crashes issue at all.   I feel there is some kind of timing issue but really has no clue no control.
The issue drives me crazy. Please help. thanks!

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Dim quit As Integer
Dim added As Boolean
added = Add_Addin
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
If Workbooks.Count = 1 Then
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:03")
    Application.quit
Else
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:03")
    Me.Close
End If

End Sub


Private Function Add_Addin() As Boolean
    On Error GoTo ERR_

Dim addinFile As String

addinFile = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "MyAdd-In.xll"

If Len(addinFile) > 0 Then
        Dim LEA As AddIn
        Set LEA = Application.AddIns.Add(addinFile)
        If (Not LEA Is Nothing) Then
            LEA.Installed = True
        Else
            MsgBox "Failed to add XLL"
        End If

    'If (Application.RegisterXLL(addinFile) = True) Then
     '   MsgBox "Yeah, succeed registering XLL"
    'Else
     '   MsgBox "Failed to register XLL"
    'End If

Else
    MsgBox "XLL file not found"
End If

addinFile = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "MyFunc.xla"
If Len(addinFile) > 0 Then
        Dim LEA2 As AddIn
        Set LEA2 = Application.AddIns.Add(addinFile)
        If (Not LEA2 Is Nothing) Then
            LEA2.Installed = True
        Else
            MsgBox "Failed to add xla"
        End If
Else
    MsgBox "xla file not found"
End If

Add_Addin = True

Exit Function

ERR_:
    MsgBox ("Error " & Err.Number & " " & Err.Description)
    Add_Addin = False

End Function
```

Comment: What are these Waits supposed to accomplish/what problem are they trying to solve?

Comment: That's only for debug. I was thinking the timing issue caused the crashes. but it turns out not. I figured out. I kicked off a web service call asychronously When Excel opens. When the callback of the web service call is executed after Excel is disposed or close, the crash occurred.  I fixed it by checking if Excel is null or disposed before doing anything else in the callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I kicked off a web service call asychronously with callback When Excel opens. When the callback of the web service call is executed after Excel is disposed or close, the crash occurred. The callback disbales/enables ribbon buttons based on the result from web service. I fixed it by checking if Excel is null or disposed before doing anything else in the callback.